# datetime Problems in Python IDLE

Tags: python, datetime, python-idle

I have a weird problem. I have two Python 3.4.3 installations - one on Windows XP, the other on Windows 7 x64.

Only the one on WinXP exhibits these problems:

When I open the Python IDLE shell, I can execute `dir(datetime)` before I `import` anything and it will print some attributes (but the list is shorter than on Windows 7, after importing `datetime`).

The following fails in IDLE, because attribute `now` is not found:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.now()
```

The regular Python command prompt works fine.

It would seem that IDLE already has some version of `datetime` imported, but it differs from the standard `datetime` module.

Unfortunately, I do not have access to the XP machine right now, so I can't run any tests right now. I was certain that the same problems would be present on the Windows 7 machine, but they aren't.

Comment: Try `print(datetime.__file__)` to see where it's getting imported from - clearly you've shadowed the standard library on one of the machines.

Comment: For me, with 3.4.3 on Win10 upgraded from win7, `dir(datetime)` as the first statement entered in Shell fails, while `import datetime; datetime.datetime.now()` works. `import sys; 'datetime' in sys.modules` fails, because IDLE apparently does not import datetime on startup, either directly or indirectly.  `datetime` does not appear in any idlelib file.  Something must be peculiar about your machine, as jonrsharpe suggests.